# How to draw a line between a data point and an axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib one can use:

- `plt.hlines/vlines` to draw segments (e.g. between two data points)
- `plt.axhline/axvline` to draw lines relative to the axes

My question is: *what is the simplest way to do half of each?* Typically, drawing a segment from a datapoint to its coordinate on the x or y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is simple enough (4 lines):

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
ax.plot(x, y)
# starting from here
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.vlines(x[i], ymin, y[i])
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

Output:

[image]